# Error in `[.default`(tab, 1:m, 1:m) : subscript out of bounds using caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, feature-selection

I want to perform recursive feature elimination using the caret package.

```
library(caret)
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
results <- rfe(meth.clin[,-which(names(meth.clin)=="subtype")], meth.clin$subtype, rfeControl=control)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `[.default`(tab, 1:m, 1:m) : subscript out of bounds
```

Dimensions:

```
> dim(meth.clin)
[1] 202 325
```

Data:

```
> dput(meth.clin[1:3,])
structure(list(cg01418261 = c(0.0329289428076256, 0.0342857142857143, 
0.0555737436568997), cg04567445 = c(0.128681384523206, 0.0993347285715956, 
0.3147952933132), cg05171584 = c(0.210483022938392, 0.151531564060901, 
0.348212726186281), cg00655307 = c(0.0577533066012329, 0.0629074450857451, 
0.170598046223493), cg00446065 = c(0.940806142034549, 0.971945635583981, 
0.971031361138054), cg06147752 = c(0.709208075269186, 0.790425763687619, 
0.666223356457352), cg04478684 = c(0.916770963704631, 0.911426203848633, 
0.9453891242528), cg08129310 = c(0.723112274206932, 0.3692372961252, 
0.557802576899014), cg08458121 = c(0.887565040343866, 0.612940582593461, 
0.974038330841376), cg02485462 = c(0.654472404313808, 0.489852291230519, 
0.916691649178908), cg07924874 = c(0.0529090991031592, 0.0542798960747139, 
0.100966593182974), cg02242734 = c(0.91010718747945, 0.882785130400934, 
0.890939833732563), cg04351734 = c(0.28878787474839, 0.251142490372272, 
0.569197735701737), cg06081580 = c(0.88177254630431, 0.847911848728064, 
0.843014357554114), cg09495643 = c(0.686352586843842, 0.687236756844322, 
0.638389894505595), cg03178838 = c(0.717146928435719, 0.708466725699884, 
0.641686417197984), cg06145336 = c(0.698400609291698, 0.790132158590308, 
0.550081662355945), cg01860753 = c(0.0485649702034386, 0.0820262040966968, 
0.0512269256431166), cg02049847 = c(0.0459550389967885, 0.0613159197963814, 
0.0927679210756623), cg07570075 = c(0.0399607746996813, 0.070202380299457, 
0.059313793582442), cg08369258 = c(0.0259799801329564, 0.0455971303127565, 
0.035031847133758), cg05225883 = c(0.656074495452734, 0.681214297372287, 
0.596488837118363), cg02313013 = c(0.205626166861671, 0.219360541314883, 
0.408783882569666), cg03182113 = c(0.0790871048282168, 0.0942035545095199, 
0.231815620723887), cg03655371 = c(0.23421926910299, 0.302050774344106, 
0.561283625983911), cg01628067 = c(0.524141698533429, 0.608487945274366, 
0.430554679119076), cg05893614 = c(0.065097462302317, 0.0608494591764471, 
0.276838128451032), cg07795016 = c(0.767461913953732, 0.467357783300608, 
0.654978089844782), cg02908258 = c(0.940208908396667, 0.923684591969851, 
0.935495218462381), cg04253465 = c(0.924744164654479, 0.900094794543132, 
0.686712227193081), cg07841866 = c(0.558846534688731, 0.66064044619675, 
0.741945817316493), cg02968760 = c(0.937573555748861, 0.910417320363979, 
0.94290227939517), cg02064543 = c(0.0231660115272385, 0.0185449358059914, 
0.02763671875), cg05181025 = c(0.0559434531505905, 0.070243771405547, 
0.0474828870981717), cg09166022 = c(0.0454991660296059, 0.0375518166300902, 
0.0425511570089883), cg04398180 = c(0.891923850065035, 0.462989594788935, 
0.818779721101201), cg00774435 = c(0.861780854619241, 0.861992470959501, 
0.893249877145281), cg08770961 = c(0.808922911309132, 0.833214986842655, 
0.904925751539297), cg09244174 = c(0.923264559406444, 0.896986906452122, 
0.903196831747846), cg06271190 = c(0.569616475152962, 0.457882228677053, 
0.450976691516467), cg01777019 = c(0.114097543609826, 0.0627443792766373, 
0.0871700940804263), cg01973676 = c(0.830987540378403, 0.828929556279769, 
0.502887284841755), cg08453784 = c(0.0330093796741797, 0.028301019939355, 
0.0211675494417559), cg01175020 = c(0.0727845443091138, 0.0904195224824885, 
0.239089643841769), cg02517686 = c(0.902437373053487, 0.925132598939209, 
0.702322759680746), cg05727199 = c(0.504617414248021, 0.430743243243243, 
0.451914098972923), cg02001060 = c(0.376436195526548, 0.442119944211994, 
0.555665192242259), cg07774251 = c(0.361663286004057, 0.522791070712472, 
0.573303889093363), cg07925758 = c(0.645435095226404, 0.875255550959222, 
0.842500891607912), cg01629240 = c(0.766155436843012, 0.804323582396843, 
0.411049231454667), cg00435098 = c(0.940964005480134, 0.936417608823515, 
0.978401291885345), cg07385694 = c(0.376453157054935, 0.29599761051374, 
0.547174912138416), cg00610508 = c(0.897568455640745, 0.816218693167987, 
0.773706473933384), cg02516134 = c(0.927238465746763, 0.724971409403491, 
0.658664259927798), cg04181032 = c(0.803718269574544, 0.761902053353052, 
0.707293291731669), cg09223687 = c(0.838396176314392, 0.747426802795983, 
0.712642713230356), cg03357952 = c(0.894450335807706, 0.851505819719192, 
0.790762216275151), cg01603079 = c(0.361201298701299, 0.191419383131121, 
0.29928027391517), cg00702647 = c(0.767841971112999, 0.411340051135509, 
0.26661405783214), cg07138437 = c(0.913637381503322, 0.926322961617079, 
0.906314344543583), cg02220837 = c(0.188366164542294, 0.887061072542509, 
0.434544549527128), cg07031551 = c(0.0733693903284937, 0.0841529678794965, 
0.0522261337751087), cg02442619 = c(0.199219275811011, 0.179327588041281, 
0.326644476145189), cg09463706 = c(0.384398289015302, 0.282524928670177, 
0.50046693515438), cg02016985 = c(0.924155816661374, 0.903591489361702, 
0.930672033993067), cg04862799 = c(0.034588710385392, 0.0216007513304811, 
0.0392911392405063), cg00996262 = c(0.00943581581008991, 0.0364612411423663, 
0.0461892693781679), cg05872129 = c(0.0256590572687049, 0.0553504261706753, 
0.04297440849831), cg02630629 = c(0.899525898651542, 0.843819562401595, 
0.847243993729806), cg05408649 = c(0.855706491278835, 0.826463870936392, 
0.761803030184026), cg05143887 = c(0.032396214685363, 0.049789755351682, 
0.0618306515431285), cg02200944 = c(0.938279759283722, 0.92739188770771, 
0.934484609005317), cg02177317 = c(0.592203431982094, 0.52359224307788, 
0.625259875259875), cg03476000 = c(0.350968582125997, 0.211695265912133, 
0.304426283604408), cg05751100 = c(0.042234108857384, 0.0550046663555763, 
0.0498373917401998), cg05914034 = c(0.888376877185764, 0.849749396695749, 
0.859728600650545), cg08859513 = c(0.0457851669047928, 0.0601890413935465, 
0.0404466134279799), cg03728674 = c(0.725719971256426, 0.526099176872114, 
0.501530208727348), cg09497409 = c(0.123602892833662, 0.147193347193347, 
0.364941711686096), cg04255391 = c(0.0722964264509246, 0.542618799344555, 
0.604086845466156), cg06803853 = c(0.903375573519773, 0.5001145883731, 
0.688423092994612), cg03524868 = c(0.887065386611313, 0.871678943357887, 
0.894104852961167), cg09096824 = c(0.859059843307218, 0.738021999655486, 
0.590548915449314), cg05278650 = c(0.0443908070101795, 0.0466242336678511, 
0.034313559772241), cg07084376 = c(0.939843382389509, 0.932651700377862, 
0.928127128263337), cg00466108 = c(0.0320560058953574, 0.0456925615092174, 
0.0483097802403038), cg04028224 = c(0.0283685412503568, 0.0213347747289434, 
0.0333412717313646), cg00064020 = c(0.440538618569321, 0.286609880749574, 
0.618706804709482), cg02069390 = c(0.568352916530764, 0.501225212143214, 
0.755508943389268), cg08201700 = c(0.097572641396628, 0.0573735656608585, 
0.0879066710483076), cg08167047 = c(0.0176781360065023, 0.0236760941521341, 
0.0316508412460436), cg03924776 = c(0.319499188499884, 0.309377625541265, 
0.508798592225244), cg01864791 = c(0.377640101379893, 0.760736196319018, 
0.608397320699232), cg04552206 = c(0.15223941230238, 0.186227131515361, 
0.279137956311391), cg08441633 = c(0.813187262396272, 0.795078330318441, 
0.828587030716724), cg07458308 = c(0.157502915059647, 0.119253657033121, 
0.517483593109106), cg06931267 = c(0.337018397821962, 0.571032440436129, 
0.574654752233956), cg04179953 = c(0.940601044067159, 0.537596430895065, 
0.932058544251989), cg04917197 = c(0.120427548628448, 0.125866611241873, 
0.31576715353049), cg07434944 = c(0.837673611111111, 0.828648923546364, 
0.813511233801089), cg08529179 = c(0.401505366766134, 0.379148508213208, 
0.840834607821717), cg00825967 = c(0.850901473778709, 0.84468528553564, 
0.639729477933819), cg06200013 = c(0.140054054054054, 0.0360301609944977, 
0.103339686748985), cg02705837 = c(0.059535197794159, 0.0559869227625664, 
0.0788452471620788), cg06889535 = c(0.125424304141208, 0.0889897051125458, 
0.231213006668165), cg01613455 = c(0.0517501964814703, 0.0492697356258088, 
0.0480472197705207), cg04803128 = c(0.0530386646033408, 0.0765153542801535, 
0.097283198710902), cg02396496 = c(0.0300277567499369, 0.0256600621780892, 
0.0424189860443113), cg06376715 = c(0.295383127870438, 0.442806183115339, 
0.730714320878255), cg02367696 = c(0.127467948717949, 0.102934377634549, 
0.274741929026908), cg06008724 = c(0.0260568356110087, 0.0651561699948797, 
0.0868640169288803), cg03667968 = c(0.0695599269924965, 0.0546009927453226, 
0.0612315818737837), cg08239804 = c(0.167792679237673, 0.169659326181065, 
0.39244024785096), cg06927337 = c(0.341444050065384, 0.216691195567483, 
0.669216799969089), cg04826413 = c(0.920393350503395, 0.907267712700631, 
0.901766969909027), cg03016189 = c(0.0353258938090838, 0.0287017787017787, 
0.0423953365129836), cg09530163 = c(0.471909231131212, 0.512570288409215, 
0.375087076372013), cg09350341 = c(0.0351348756839781, 0.0362495051744613, 
0.0726630196336514), cg08025954 = c(0.684002856889983, 0.422356828193833, 
0.460771184483953), cg02237342 = c(0.746393802865315, 0.623618051420138, 
0.566966370854741), cg01301319 = c(0.380406768265352, 0.360244353755291, 
0.816783820742269), cg00656647 = c(0.0156946232300228, 0.0434804140048532, 
0.0272287829651839), cg03270395 = c(0.76873920552677, 0.771000228885328, 
0.570416127950965), cg08305551 = c(0.0309299363057325, 0.0358391608391608, 
0.0751957148743305), cg04705659 = c(0.663445885627265, 0.362650112553426, 
0.191515229076017), cg02814118 = c(0.780206540447504, 0.796310491082835, 
0.768627450980392), cg05278271 = c(0.0499744225396451, 0.0477252885827917, 
0.0738486508419558), cg03495084 = c(0.521922873745378, 0.120295281760689, 
0.191923990498812), cg00271522 = c(0.0272209567198178, 0.108396221436487, 
0.133053911900066), cg02294791 = c(0.664876551820338, 0.424216075213304, 
0.684453105666914), cg01290644 = c(0.978380988144413, 0.971033622997103, 
0.977128614888392), cg04988994 = c(0.933354160158284, 0.990966034423218, 
0.942062213409344), cg00291661 = c(0.965862974456911, 0.958333054505303, 
0.965600030854873), cg08038353 = c(0.110227126908764, 0.115598156295831, 
0.218710126435448), cg04833050 = c(0.141341975399573, 0.0914335812664385, 
0.305343511450382), cg02382795 = c(0.686922702965484, 0.455022643062989, 
0.560489352061622), cg02110858 = c(0.569377990430622, 0.363547040039302, 
0.378372922414373), cg05595301 = c(0.321748878923767, 0.215885493918718, 
0.194996686547382), cg04889072 = c(0.0498145790668069, 0.0561428160827771, 
0.0794603898963212), cg05629774 = c(0.886352492508853, 0.899996410495711, 
0.905137994346166), cg07006673 = c(0.289452299691208, 0.150358896864375, 
0.550873614049824), cg07060908 = c(0.95356053715692, 0.938092157832655, 
0.921054524528845), cg01373896 = c(0.863808685130725, 0.850936602552362, 
0.855281132178569), cg02633761 = c(0.0492718629744209, 0.0319797201774484, 
0.030307700693365), cg00023808 = c(0.849008684253646, 0.909586353479754, 
0.948526470196026), cg08734647 = c(0.116336633663366, 0.0822165336545701, 
0.464289656694999), cg05885410 = c(0.104371453688164, 0.0926775612822124, 
0.191076459038784), cg00345344 = c(0.366439215607543, 0.363124793114863, 
0.576998493847509), cg09065876 = c(0.558290857824531, 0.823992871547156, 
0.587896867675261), cg03862380 = c(0.260604787904242, 0.149695131892139, 
0.469326170579652), cg08764037 = c(0.274804281834159, 0.568529167563578, 
0.64120384666081), cg03760518 = c(0.539597173890119, 0.458639557753782, 
0.609532947805191), cg07300846 = c(0.0702138966387671, 0.472352424198037, 
0.593854171886745), cg01558909 = c(0.278225806451613, 0.0690683485295126, 
0.0622702026128452), cg02660823 = c(0.123796880185861, 0.0715095194922937, 
0.1112828438949), cg04589210 = c(0.815541552283504, 0.780079755748022, 
0.77027736788135), cg04362711 = c(0.927278177458034, 0.902588796607174, 
0.915053546170944), cg05012676 = c(0.907543959160522, 0.958603374788346, 
0.915243865124533), cg00853940 = c(0.0936149103536248, 0.0441553508688634, 
0.137206600046479), cg04895288 = c(0.164426217057796, 0.0694880110585358, 
0.306755581327921), cg08758174 = c(0.825800880042768, 0.959246122817998, 
0.961995603412944), cg07441518 = c(0.462655582658391, 0.161338943666395, 
0.370042080759244), cg09240693 = c(0.807401636151149, 0.86841009747608, 
0.796749521988528), cg08832624 = c(0.111453092630956, 0.115030931282394, 
0.539288094599037), cg00700487 = c(0.276681627118511, 0.253424622995212, 
0.481613342572459), cg02659532 = c(0.880484114977307, 0.860386715702664, 
0.818470075307174), cg08550353 = c(0.156895947681887, 0.130045229377558, 
0.457588477961931), cg09221960 = c(0.738057576716229, 0.727940124898699, 
0.950431661654865), cg04994084 = c(0.0236297198538368, 0.0340809628008753, 
0.0531982267257758), cg07870914 = c(0.836410226544756, 0.779478204241117, 
0.704930032292788), cg03444587 = c(0.881215264912931, 0.871955719557196, 
0.90836606325488), cg05662444 = c(0.850344849887514, 0.861241453277919, 
0.857979953739399), cg02669989 = c(0.0341672457725272, 0.0445672455863356, 
0.0554865424430642), cg00256155 = c(0.6675590407863, 0.267644362969753, 
0.232489243140298), cg04933208 = c(0.0357142857142857, 0.0282361122400137, 
0.030722699777141), cg03894975 = c(0.0742956868611319, 0.0915607689801238, 
0.0991219963031423), cg06485940 = c(0.106822584116508, 0.0811050814010853, 
0.168990661379046), cg02511809 = c(0.156130762091368, 0.0916444343531816, 
0.199800531914894), cg08180952 = c(0.0439105820873857, 0.071062542446132, 
0.0769763277099731), cg07160932 = c(0.144308943089431, 0.487917711991972, 
0.609003405893677), cg03920233 = c(0.0659092677612637, 0.0575330805540509, 
0.114821090401674), cg06563504 = c(0.0898817345597897, 0.0779794187178418, 
0.147325668992172), cg00593111 = c(0.35806148920903, 0.421273045771834, 
0.439887666408251), cg06239131 = c(0.964523395105969, 0.569710508599057, 
0.659275506357312), cg08101036 = c(0.349237992054893, 0.195150548729012, 
0.861492464457868), cg00921266 = c(0.325859782389824, 0.18910362424987, 
0.880766712304304), cg08485649 = c(0.758080462392577, 0.704895661568204, 
0.62324085243265), cg04675427 = c(0.859784220062593, 0.904155733635912, 
0.895240833932423), cg01373166 = c(0.821438190142742, 0.837693539775761, 
0.708193008076774), cg05398905 = c(0.885403992609617, 0.890106160620012, 
0.697582346259938), cg06697522 = c(0.883228568123096, 0.868975377283558, 
0.857873570962158), cg05841263 = c(0.889295580110497, 0.865990485593753, 
0.825141451414514), cg05829046 = c(0.891408245451839, 0.4422016611846, 
0.746733883942937), cg02379560 = c(0.0633005108462279, 0.0534561289353822, 
0.104449496589802), cg07243576 = c(0.887783433595558, 0.865035355368859, 
0.764951182360726), cg06458238 = c(0.897056924335261, 0.89524326041757, 
0.875389337787207), cg07368661 = c(0.9337200247589, 0.891686658945511, 
0.871000952871209), cg07371521 = c(0.875285062713797, 0.888108957569408, 
0.802394715111478), cg05711506 = c(0.969362084456424, 0.812644673536275, 
0.942819636886089), cg01021488 = c(0.100260939381774, 0.204443753225362, 
0.172597273029598), cg06879394 = c(0.732718894009217, 0.688456435420219, 
0.144208430136077), cg07512361 = c(0.313691440919966, 0.937831740976645, 
0.855020236181183), cg03071221 = c(0.538996676200046, 0.693472474305986, 
0.873339405169436), cg06807117 = c(0.620923984366425, 0.643727096718006, 
0.49781955223374), cg09085216 = c(0.647790186339334, 0.372040277154678, 
0.217959072336142), cg06759629 = c(0.0776567957033428, 0.179593925951203, 
0.236305655350583), cg01218619 = c(0.0483163633593656, 0.0925568266230872, 
0.149958672806707), cg06418973 = c(0.894994559303591, 0.424280104712042, 
0.792725343394447), cg05789359 = c(0.956857507838811, 0.974234557717502, 
0.981019816098736), cg04584009 = c(0.374726553409355, 0.303571428571429, 
0.536942259471714), cg05613116 = c(0.0543364071436909, 0.35166041533254, 
0.530707519376331), cg01798251 = c(0.11727842435094, 0.0779334500875657, 
0.065008171418195), cg04444959 = c(0.911209964412811, 0.930163349670605, 
0.629471828399324), cg07770854 = c(0.134769571735871, 0.151596103082813, 
0.200374457236187), cg01061424 = c(0.332254316725058, 0.327758583789403, 
0.545992302327384), cg06523556 = c(0.056371263765076, 0.0509613157285152, 
0.079498789091292), cg03718353 = c(0.897393068066575, 0.894738927184851, 
0.899665551839465), cg07412043 = c(0.9131633356306, 0.915975422427035, 
0.755045140732873), cg07050616 = c(0.0413089105132608, 0.047517258296247, 
0.0832302719659932), cg04037228 = c(0.374669815617233, 0.468806257371656, 
0.420200748175858), cg08664810 = c(0.0847321428571429, 0.0865831012070566, 
0.163197446299129), cg07591090 = c(0.929707215033894, 0.928983138091171, 
0.941921213551717), cg05070626 = c(0.0997526793075021, 0.355298651252409, 
0.106679328901551), cg03602288 = c(0.643179045390036, 0.64317649332404, 
0.509236035369009), cg08122789 = c(0.0422323497309615, 0.0305843435695438, 
0.042773872792731), cg04379969 = c(0.0580560035185457, 0.0315271499685301, 
0.0175043153160824), cg02779164 = c(0.907810053922421, 0.923419412288513, 
0.939633193519204), cg06537894 = c(0.0368051313378131, 0.048094709581946, 
0.107965070124372), cg05068987 = c(0.0735472981011338, 0.0602636670936457, 
0.114500582565406), cg00927435 = c(0.898787513973687, 0.846025920403716, 
0.889186674111297), cg08834902 = c(0.906200390075747, 0.900221257002655, 
0.827011580688825), cg06857887 = c(0.909836406776839, 0.875505895718638, 
0.874685736863878), cg03696974 = c(0.153295982834664, 0.379219254476079, 
0.661174998510397), cg01585096 = c(0.548912761430277, 0.791309239206863, 
0.472056631892697), cg01014615 = c(0.859942710688979, 0.786612169352973, 
0.65469046714774), cg02251742 = c(0.0981293252595156, 0.105870058736622, 
0.186737024493975), cg01394884 = c(0.940598860467936, 0.950801191722361, 
0.936872214461518), cg00862376 = c(0.165235556204806, 0.15258716902929, 
0.197505850938098), cg09192572 = c(0.0986979772146013, 0.0927252606441843, 
0.107774032076821), cg05391318 = c(0.0544427324088341, 0.0340038038153421, 
0.14934826990525), cg01890845 = c(0.0627827129543844, 0.487718812703245, 
0.151359885608746), cg07369950 = c(0.0892238278951154, 0.0875973771226812, 
0.217306898272006), cg08754654 = c(0.65185046728972, 0.60195423623995, 
0.582077553824342), cg06322432 = c(0.331262409530519, 0.242603272846626, 
0.344256699095409), cg06059056 = c(0.0463572879005497, 0.0482198409955064, 
0.0706342215371064), cg01675953 = c(0.932000167693791, 0.904625850340136, 
0.873796998871801), cg07005294 = c(0.0508216897125896, 0.041682517254497, 
0.0888665679847748), cg08092199 = c(0.44038546832789, 0.43529312621141, 
0.551165146909828), cg06256858 = c(0.0404069350909873, 0.0717158730345958, 
0.113193460993781), cg06410591 = c(0.0439087407463749, 0.0377220734972013, 
0.164553503115095), cg00716083 = c(0.318887509872504, 0.244588420815499, 
0.590579408086703), cg01135546 = c(0.471302890657729, 0.660060579835569, 
0.338022804776581), cg08928675 = c(0.885861179706222, 0.855459974795902, 
0.885735180152155), cg07018435 = c(0.786461602845784, 0.287379624936645, 
0.870848857929694), cg00111335 = c(0.971661960467931, 0.541259958845565, 
0.924031174031174), cg00880018 = c(0.0573694363077802, 0.072360099446068, 
0.628222222222222), cg04561791 = c(0.858770046549374, 0.627407298842152, 
0.543635430292096), cg07387700 = c(0.263519706691109, 0.144039735099338, 
0.278656512399922), cg00425213 = c(0.49453190722269, 0.331156061244557, 
0.554841926212681), cg07423838 = c(0.0810249080341314, 0.0931766977792082, 
0.101564995209198), cg07780630 = c(0.834939759036145, 0.788176783090313, 
0.693819559554819), cg04323427 = c(0.0784983821290986, 0.130530973451327, 
0.192138457025521), cg00329447 = c(0.474228127607677, 0.41029983978027, 
0.389249351167898), cg00523450 = c(0.145154373927959, 0.177489177489178, 
0.331650279032687), cg08385610 = c(0.933090578060992, 0.903060046189376, 
0.930242407406564), cg04993276 = c(0.369871794871795, 0.226837732674309, 
0.289743329613473), cg09235539 = c(0.110969927996612, 0.105144063961382, 
0.233765015015015), cg09337254 = c(0.0666311789863984, 0.0716923468738062, 
0.28242640499554), cg02242344 = c(0.0759809247661273, 0.0631169654383402, 
0.15083426028921), cg07245678 = c(0.0599625818521983, 0.0573843416370107, 
0.124676631215867), cg07514207 = c(0.049317617866005, 0.042040285899935, 
0.0436160023576217), cg08626939 = c(0.0852257781674704, 0.0640219717834429, 
0.108155161559213), cg07129852 = c(0.0584596135131378, 0.0736933877850686, 
0.0632406863048456), cg00862408 = c(0.711889967254507, 0.739529013186302, 
0.633676389145283), cg04833430 = c(0.039644550084101, 0.0626953484096341, 
0.0300360432519023), cg05835276 = c(0.0348904991468847, 0.0321178459309346, 
0.129572327258178), cg00531400 = c(0.0476672887230072, 0.0593947490109438, 
0.0499229583975347), cg07781162 = c(0.166092350103377, 0.109544172504777, 
0.154267815191856), cg08287334 = c(0.976324773638118, 0.979832203936754, 
0.959500351864884), cg07532993 = c(0.0251120548708141, 0.0199778024417314, 
0.0263269149467697), cg02895995 = c(0.0516967916296556, 0.0610276238689361, 
0.0799573560767591), cg01682111 = c(0.261492338441039, 0.828635346756152, 
0.783084214363835), cg02776664 = c(0.0268480616421864, 0.0341778308352125, 
0.136670508809485), cg05164396 = c(0.907846410684474, 0.93427065026362, 
0.933097494753314), cg02557189 = c(0.0721142589557481, 0.0838898476776469, 
0.180865358774523), cg04346572 = c(0.185372536621351, 0.0577136514983352, 
0.135561308543187), cg06889746 = c(0.0529064174797307, 0.039059692198203, 
0.0779518072289157), cg01224063 = c(0.0179981674593132, 0.0289590927501013, 
0.0154062975955011), cg05894734 = c(0.0487649402390438, 0.0541861222716907, 
0.0616228992530019), cg04917391 = c(0.0964620267864055, 0.181669567051627, 
0.201869806094183), cg05732436 = c(0.0206316861946001, 0.0305338498916541, 
0.02823712017193), cg02931247 = c(0.677629835718071, 0.837245696400626, 
0.870052034991312), cg01283201 = c(0.0329704510108865, 0.0302309958141698, 
0.0493418259023355), cg09245872 = c(0.426439522998296, 0.254400574768949, 
0.784591361422824), cg09093210 = c(0.138637560438508, 0.163534059619298, 
0.29791405569797), cg04858586 = c(0.738918439716312, 0.646320495185695, 
0.72771236333053), cg09187695 = c(0.652882820940969, 0.203590017349526, 
0.912106415221418), cg06802147 = c(0.0416751892002454, 0.0140692009340576, 
0.0458802724181645), cg02007463 = c(0.0414302317631777, 0.0409302325581395, 
0.0480637677711023), cg06520675 = c(0.121226250145705, 0.109124537607891, 
0.158992678839199), cg00314018 = c(0.0967789380791293, 0.0559194481220821, 
0.114953842879566), cg05113709 = c(0.0304615384615385, 0.0518145885734819, 
0.0493030459473413), cg06082883 = c(0.845025781730451, 0.841103230198292, 
0.739466866648486), cg01020413 = c(0.0921441774491682, 0.0938681360927789, 
0.165634291377602), cg02676167 = c(0.571642053445851, 0.538579208223704, 
0.320272819619794), cg07036370 = c(0.0940937122512556, 0.0630272833076787, 
0.190728614489138), cg04005480 = c(0.0502092050209205, 0.0611959435831682, 
0.0831494925995748), cg07078095 = c(0.0603015075376884, 0.344779910613807, 
0.376844627567868), cg04877910 = c(0.0939936471267687, 0.0532876581977353, 
0.150829562594268), cg03022609 = c(0.0596081014325704, 0.0876306456168984, 
0.137928720048325), cg04137128 = c(0.0399948393755644, 0.044956554590102, 
0.072710103871577), cg06499484 = c(0.0743780456527315, 0.0557450703053499, 
0.100884955752212), cg03476616 = c(0.230943560688603, 0.26120385003898, 
0.451283286313906), cg04263702 = c(0.873114684804119, 0.829658102366984, 
0.682871153195807), cg07011172 = c(0.039508611642694, 0.0351178781925344, 
0.140094231055632), cg09082287 = c(0.110793521165101, 0.0806981485834231, 
0.32456837390739), cg04994405 = c(0.164460446891878, 0.119690630150881, 
0.338178256611166), cg01920657 = c(0.0263786528309498, 0.0329389735296621, 
0.0873633777511603), cg01604412 = c(0.250212472368956, 0.294388620996202, 
0.465618410528612), cg09467436 = c(0.391078193023124, 0.250262079481559, 
0.572070155533494), cg07875759 = c(0.0357821552723059, 0.0451291619807109, 
0.0327477400648132), cg02241241 = c(0.0613052892050727, 0.0512285209571222, 
0.082611955558585), cg01490894 = c(0.0442676950269141, 0.0532912113522192, 
0.0584795321637427), cg04945557 = c(0.67063236464214, 0.381480855862644, 
0.687438686287055), subtype = c("2a", "1a", "1b")), row.names = c("TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01", 
"TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01", "TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01"), class = "data.frame")
```